# I am not able to change the screen using kivy in python

Tags: python, kivy

I want to change the screen using a function that is in another class. I can do this in the kv file but not in the python file. Here is a part of the code

```
main.py
self.dialog = MDDialog(
                            title="It looks like you already have an account. Please login instead.",
                            buttons=[
                                MDFlatButton(
                                    text="OK", text_color=theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=self.close_dialog
                                ),
                                MDFlatButton(
                                    text="Login", text_color=theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=MainApp.change_screen('login_screen', 'Right')
                                )
                            ],
                        )
                        self.dialog.open()
```

```
Function for changing screen in main.py
class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        # theme_cls = ThemeManager()
        return Builder.load_file("main1.kv")

    def change_screen(self, screen, direction):
        self.root.transition.direction = direction
        self.root.current = screen
```

```
main.kv
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "Register"
        elevation: 10
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        left_action_items: [['arrow-left', lambda screen: app.change_screen('welcome_screen', 'right')]]
```

It works in the KV file but when i try and do the same thing in the python file i get this error  TypeError: change_screen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'direction']

[Updated]

```
main.py
import re
from re import search

from mysql import connector
import requests
import json
import functools
import operator

from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from mysql.connector import Error
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

global theme_cls
theme_cls = ThemeManager()
mydb = connector




class SqlConnection():

    def connect(self):
        global mydb
        mydb = connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="kelvinc7",
            password="B352627u",
        )

        if mydb:
            print("Successful")
        else:
            print("Unsuccessful")


class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    dialog = None

    def validate(self):
        if not self.ids.email.text or not self.ids.password.text:
            if not self.dialog:
                self.dialog = MDDialog(
                    title="Enter email and Password.",
                    buttons=[
                        MDFlatButton(
                            text="OK", text_color=theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=self.close_dialog
                        )
                    ],
                )

            self.dialog.open()
        else:
            pass

    def close_dialog(self, inst):
        self.dialog.dismiss()


class RegisterScreen(Screen):
    dialog = None

    sm = ScreenManager()

    def convert_tuple(self, tup):
        str = ''.join(tup)
        return str

    def validate_data(self):
        if not self.ids.firstname.text or not self.ids.surname.text or not self.ids.email.text or not self.ids.password.text or not self.ids.passconf.text:
            if not self.dialog:
                self.dialog = MDDialog(
                    title="Complete all fields to continue.",
                    buttons=[
                        MDFlatButton(
                            text="OK", text_color=theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=self.close_dialog
                        )
                    ],
                )

            self.dialog.open()
        else:
            try:
                SqlConnection.connect(None)
                email = self.ids.email.text
                password = self.ids.password.text
                firstname = self.ids.firstname.text
                lastname = self.ids.surname.text
                username = self.ids.username.text

                mysql_create_datebase = """CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `%s`""" % username
                mysql_select_database = """USE `%s`""" % username
                mysql_check_databases = """SHOW DATABASES"""

                cursor = mydb.cursor()
                cursor.execute(mysql_create_datebase)
                cursor.execute(mysql_select_database)
                cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, username VARCHAR(255), email VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(255))")
                cursor.execute(mysql_check_databases);

                for x in cursor:
                    str = self.convert_tuple(x)

                    if str == username:
                        print("Failed")

                        app = MainApp.get_running_app()

                        self.dialog = MDDialog(
                            title="It looks like you already have an account. Please login instead.",
                            buttons=[
                                MDFlatButton(
                                    text="OK", text_color=theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=self.close_dialog
                                ),
                                MDFlatButton(
                                    text="Login", text_color=theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=app.change_screen('login_screen', 'right')
                                )
                            ],
                        )
                        self.dialog.open()
                    else:
                        # print("Failed")
                        userdata = {"firstname": firstname, "lastname": lastname, "password": password, "email": email,
                                    "username": username}
                        resp = requests.post('http://localhost/registration_server.php', data=userdata)

                # print(resp.text)

            except connector.Error as error:
                print("Failed to create table {}".format(error))

            finally:
                if mydb.is_connected():
                    mydb.close()

    def close_dialog(self, inst):
        self.dialog.dismiss()




class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        # theme_cls = ThemeManager()
        return Builder.load_file("main1.kv")

    def change_screen(self, screen, direction):
        self.root.transition.direction = direction
        self.root.current = screen


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

This is my full python code i didn't want to put it on before because i thought that there would be too much to look at but i have now updated it. I have also updated the code with the help from John who i want to thank for suggesting it. This has given me another problem where the error now says that None is not callable when I press the button. Thanks in advance for the assistance. I will also post the kv file for completeness below.

```
main1.kv
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
#: import MDLabel kivymd.uix.label.MDLabel
#: import Rectangle kivy.graphics.Rectangle
#: import Color kivy.graphics.Rectangle


WindowManager:
    WelcomeScreen:
    LoginScreen:
    RegisterScreen:



<WelcomeScreen>:
    name: "welcome_screen"




    FloatLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            title: "SecureIT 24/7"
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}



        Button:

            text: 'Login'
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
            pos_hint: {"right":0.625, "top":0.80}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "login_screen"

        Button:

            text: 'Register'
            color: 1,1,1,1
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
            pos_hint: {"right":0.625, "top":0.55 }
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "register_screen"

<WhiteLabel@MDLabel>
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1

<CustomInput@MDTextField>
    multiline:False
    required: True
    mode: "line"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
    size_hint_x: (.5)
    write_tab: False

<LoginScreen>:
    name: "login_screen"
    MDBanner:
        id: banner
        text: "ioshrdioaoisdhf"

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "Register"
        elevation: 10
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        left_action_items: [['arrow-left', lambda screen: app.change_screen('welcome_screen', 'right')]]

    FloatLayout:

        CustomInput:
            id: email
            hint_text: 'Email'
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.65, "center_x": 0.5}
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"

        CustomInput:
            id: password
            hint_text: 'Password'
            password: True
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.55, "center_x": 0.5}
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'Login'
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.15
            font_size: 24
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.15, "center_x": 0.5}
            on_release: root.validate()

<RegisterScreen>:
    name: "register_screen"
    MDBanner:
        id: banner
        text: "ioshrdioaoisdhf"

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "Register"
        elevation: 10
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        left_action_items: [['arrow-left', lambda screen: app.change_screen('welcome_screen', 'right')]]

    FloatLayout:

        CustomInput:
            id: firstname
            hint_text: "First Name"
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.8, "center_x": 0.5}
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"

        CustomInput:
            id: surname
            hint_text: 'Surname'
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.7, "center_x": 0.5}
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"

        CustomInput:
            id: username
            hint_text: "Username"
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.6, "center_x": 0.5}
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"

        CustomInput:
            id: email
            hint_text: 'Email'
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5, "center_x": 0.5}
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"

        CustomInput:
            id: password
            hint_text: 'Password'
            password: True
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.4, "center_x": 0.5}
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"

        CustomInput:
            id: passconf
            hint_text: 'Confirm Password'
            password: True
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.3, "center_x": 0.5}
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'Register'
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.15
            font_size: 24
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.15, "center_x": 0.5}
            on_release: root.validate_data()
```

Comment: Which button is causing that error?

Comment: The third button down in the validate_data function in the register_screen class in main.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use kivyMD, you need to investigate which kivy classes are used as base classes for them. For example, a base class for `MDDialog` is the `ModalView`. The `ModalView` has a `auto_dismiss` attribute that us `True` by default. That can make it seem like the buttons in the `MDDialog` are working, because the dialog closes whenever you press a button. However, in your case, the buttons are not actually working at all. I suggest changing the creation of the `MDDialog` to:

```
                    self.dialog = MDDialog(
                        title="It looks like you already have an account. Please login instead.",
                        auto_dismiss=False,   # this is needed to allow the buttons to operate
                        buttons=[
                            MDFlatButton(
                                text="OK", text_color=theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=self.close_dialog
                            ),
                            MDFlatButton(
                                text="Login", text_color=theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=self.change_screen
                            ),
                        ],
                    )
                    self.dialog.open()
```

And then add a `change_screen()` method to the `RegisterScreen` class (along with the `close_dialog()` method):

```
def close_dialog(self, inst):
    self.dialog.dismiss()

def change_screen(self, inst):
    self.dialog.dismiss()
    MainApp.get_running_app().change_screen('login_screen', 'right')
```

This greatly simplifies the use of `on_release` attribute of the `MDFlatButton` by eliminating the need to use `partial` and/or `lambda`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are calling `change_screen`. Calling it as:

```
MainApp.change_screen('login_screen', 'Right')
```

will not work because the `change_screen()` method is an instance method and must be called as a method of an instance of `MainApp`. Since you have not provided a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it is impossible to provide a complete answer. However, if the code that you posted is part of the `MainApp` class, you can replace that problem code with:

```
self.change_screen('login_screen', 'Right')
```

If it is not part of the `MainApp` class, you can do something like:

```
app = App.get_running_app()
app.change_screen('login_screen', 'Right')
```

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your help. I think that might work but It has caused the error to change to "AssertionError: None is not callable". If you see this and can help me out again it would be much appreciated. I have also added the full code above I should have done that before but i didn't so thanks for the attempt sorry about that.